# NSDictionary sort by keys as floats

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

basically I have an NSDictionary with keys and values.

The keys are all numbers, but at the moment they are strings.

I want to be able to compare them as numbers in order to sort them.

eg: If I have a Dictionary like this:

```
{
  "100"  => (id)object,
  "20"   => (id)object,
  "10"   => (id)object,
  "1000" => (id)object,
}
```

I want to be able to sort it like this:

```
{
  "10"   => (id)object,
  "20"   => (id)object,
  "100"  => (id)object,
  "1000" => (id)object,
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Have you tried using one of the 'sortedArray' NSArray's instance methods? Such as sortedArrayUsingSelector and a homemade method where you compare float values of strings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what you are up to – dictionaries are inherently unsorted, there is no stable key ordering in the default implementation. If you want to walk the values by sorted keys, you can do something like this:

```
NSInteger floatSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    float v1 = [num1 floatValue];
    float v2 = [num2 floatValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}

NSArray *allKeys = [aDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [allKeys sortedArrayUsingFunction:floatSort context:NULL];
for (id key in sortedKeys)
    id val = [aDictionary objectForKey:key];
    …
```

Comment: this is what I want :) thank you. :) I tried getting `allKeys` from the dictionary, but they were still strings... and I'm not too savvy on sorting. I knew I'd have to get allKeys as an array, sort that and then output each one in the order of the array, but i wasn't sure how to sort the keys of the dictionary. thank you.

Comment: just add one return in the end of floatSort function to avoid possible compiler warnings

Comment: @Vladimir: Not sure about other compilers, but at least my LLVM 1.5 is smart enough to figure out that the function always returns a value.

Comment: ok heres a question - it won't let me use nested functions. Where do I put this function so that its not nested? Or can I turn it into a class method and use `sortUsingSelector:@selector(method:)`.

Comment: Simply put it somewhere between your methods, it will work just fine.

Comment: @zoul, checked that on gcc - it really does not produce any warning. so sorry - false alarm :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't sort a dictionary, but you can get the keys as an array, sort that, then output in that order.  sortedArrayUsingComparator will do that, and you can compare the strings with the NSNumericSearch option.

```
NSArray* keys = [myDict allKeys];
NSArray* sortedArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) { 
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch]; 
}]; 

for( NSString* aStr in sortedArray ) {
    NSLog( @"%@ has key %@", [myDict objectForKey:aStr], aStr );
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Super compact code. I love it! You know your stuff zpasternack... or at least you are great copy-paster. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `compare:options:` with `NSNumericSearch`.