# Reverse NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm just learning objective-c and I have an NSMutableDictionary with UITableViewCell sections in it.
The thing is, it's sorted on year and I'd like to reverse that order so the last year comes on top and not bottom.

Any ideas how to reverse sort an NSMutableDictionary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by sorting a dictionary? Dictionary is a key-value paired object, not indexed one. What is the meaning of sorting and reversing a dictionary? Based on the implementation, adding a new key can change the order of objects completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated, an `NSDictionary` has no order.

What you can do is order the keys in a separate array and then access the keyed objects in the dictionary in the order that the keys appear in your ordered array.

Something like this:

```
NSArray *orderedKeys = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:<your sort descriptor>];
for (NSString *key in orderedKeys)
{
    MyObject *myObject = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    // do what you will with myObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, a dictionary does not guarantee you any order. You might be interested in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779739) that shows how to get all dictionary values sorted using a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

An NSDictionary has no implied order.